# python requests Error 415

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to fetch a pdf stream through python requests from flipkart.
But on running `label.status_code` i am getting 415.

My code:

```
class FlipkartAPI:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.session = self.get_session()

    def get_session(self):
        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.token,
            'Content-type': 'application/json',})
        return session

    def fetch_labels(self, orderItemIds):
        self.session.headers.update({'Content-type':'application/octet-stream'})
        url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/labels"
        payload = {'orderItemId':','.join(orderItemIds)}
        return self.session.get(url, params=payload, stream=True)
```

Function call:

```
fk = FlipkartAPI(token)
label = fk.fetch_labels(oiids)
print label.status_code
print label.url
print label.content
```

I get:

```
415
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/labels?orderItemId=230005995
```

The link for documentation is: [Documentation](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#get-orders-labels-orderitemid-id-list)
I searched on internet and it says the error is for unsupported media type.
So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Its in documentation that header should be application/octet-stream.

Comment: Is "Content-Type" case sensitive?

Comment: @ManishGupta: that is the **Accept** header.

Comment: @TomDalton: `requests` can take headers in any case.

Comment: @ManishGupta: and in my professional opinion, that API is.. wonkey. Why demand a `Accept` header for the `GET` request, then respond with a PDF, an entirely different content type?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Atleast they are providing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set a `Content-Type` header, you are sending a GET request, which has no body so has no content to set a type *for*.

Instead, set an `Accept` header, as detailed in the documentation. Do not set that header for the whole session, just for this request:

```
def fetch_labels(self, orderItemIds):
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/labels"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'}
    payload = {'orderItemId':','.join(orderItemIds)}
    return self.session.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)
```

Comment: @ManishGupta: but do tell us about the response body when you get a 500 error.

Comment: Still throwing 500. Also if i explicitely pass header in get, will it not override the headers in session. Sorry for i am a beginner in python request.

Comment: response.content is `<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /orders/labels. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
`

Comment: @ManishGupta: time to ask Flipkart. That's a server-side problem.